# Resume Parsing First Step

Tags: java, parsing

I have multiple resumes in a format like somebody sends to a company to apply for a job. I need to parse these resumes in Java.

Do I need to convert these resumes to XML first for parsing? May the example below be a way to convert the resume in XML?

```
<Name>Varjhjh</Name>
<Experience>5</Experience>
<Age>7</Age>
.
.
.
```

Comment: What formats are the resumes? DOC, PDF?

Comment: The resume is sent in an email not as an attachment..I need to copy that resume in email and I can save it in Word,WordPad,Notepad etc..

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: I want to know that do I need to convert these resume in xml first?

Comment: What you need to do is dictated by your requirement. How can anybody else possibly know that? It sounds like you've decided on the solution before you've analysed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

resume parsing isn't trivial task, I remember couple years ago I was implementing one strategy -- the main problem is everybody construct their CV his/her own way.

e.g. one writes Date of Birth, another DOB next Birth Date -- so you have to use some dictionary for these cases.

And another interesting thing which you can have it's parsing names, especially if your target candidate has very very very long long name e.g. Frederick Gerald Hubert Irvim John Kenneth

Or for example user have few phones his landline, mobile, his reference 1 phone, two etc.

I remember these guys parsed cv not badly

www.rchilli.com/

Other Parsing vendors include: Sovren, Daxtra, Burning Glass and Hireability

But I'm not sure if they have Java integration, and not sure about their cost.

Anyway, good luck in parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Sovren which is a parsing vendor for full disclosure. Resume parsing is not a trivial task. Many company including Sovren, HireAbility, Daxtra and Burning Glass offer installed and SaaS solutions for parsing. Typical work flow is convert the non image resume/cv to text and parsing it returning HR-XML, the industry standard.